# Install highcharts extenion in yii2 manualy [without composer]

Tags: php, highcharts, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

Step 1:Downloaded highcharts extension and extract it in /vendor/miloschuman/highcharts
Step 2: added following code in extension`.php`

```
    'miloschuman/highcharts' => array (
    'name' => 'miloschuman/highcharts',
    `enter code here`   'version' => '4',
    'alias' => array (
        '@miloschuman/highcharts' => $vendorDir . 'miloschuman/highcharts',
    ),
   ),
```

step3: added code in `autoload_psr4.php`

```
'miloschuman\\highcharts\\' => array($vendorDir . '/miloschuman/highcharts'),
```

Step 4 :in view

```
use miloschuman\highcharts\Highcharts;
```

but getting error

> Class 'miloschuman\highcharts\Highcharts' not found

Answer (score 1):

You are missing /src when editing autoload_psr4.php

'miloschuman\highcharts\' => array($vendorDir . '/miloschuman/highcharts/src'),

Answer (score 0):

Please visit https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts
It worked fine for me. Hope this work fine for you also.
You can download the ZIP file and follow the process accordingly as given in the link.

Comment: i downloaded it from there. where i did the mistake? Please check my steps

Comment: have you added "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "dev-master"
 file in the require section of your composer.json file

Comment: check that your /vendor folder is in sync with your server.

Comment: Yes it is..can you provide me step by step process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80631/discussion-between-praveen-and-ankush-rishi).